# How to print only the MediaBox of a PDF?

Tags: linux, pdf, printing

How do you print only the `MediaBox` of a PDF ?

I tried changing `MediaBox` into `CropBox` and `TrimBox` but it didn't help (the PDF has garbage outside the MediaBox I want to get rid off before printing).

The solution should preferably be automatizable and usable under GNU/Linux.

Comment: Have you done some actual printing? Does the "garbage" appear in print? Note that the MediaBox is essentially the paper. A well-behaving renderer would also not display/print anything outside of the CropBox.

Comment: @MaxWyss When viewed with evince, only the relevant part of the PDF (a postal label), contained in the MediaBox, is displayed.  In print preview the label is surrounded with instructions on how to use the label, which is what I want to discard.  With CropBox and TrimBox, either the behaviour was similar or everything was displayed when viewing the PDF.

Comment: Which printing application do you print with? If it prints stuff beyond the media box, it seems broken or at least mis-configured for your task.

Comment: @mkl : You're right, see my comment to Vel Genov's answer — I'll have to file a bug report or two…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of the CropBox is usually the MediaBox of a document. Also, in the general case, the CropBox is a subset of the MediaBox. That will of course depend on the PDF file you are dealing with.

The MediaBox is by definition, the size of the page you are going to be displaying/printing.

The CropBox is the region of the page that will get cropped and displayed/printed. Basically, everything in the CropBox gets printed, and everything outside of it does not, unless you specify differently during the printing.

Here is a [link](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) to the PDF reference. On page 145, you can find details about what each box does. Also, there is a nice diagram of how the boxes on a page are set up on page 964. That should give you some more information on what might be going on in your particular case.

There might be something else going on here. During the actual printing process, you can chose a setting to print printer marks, and colors. This could be what you are seeing. Disabling that setting, should fix the issue.

I know this information sounds more general, but that's the most I can give you without seeing the actual document. You can leave a comment and let me know if this doesn't work, or point me to some more specific information, and I can adjust my answer.

Comment: It seems this behaviour is not properly implemented in all PDF viewers.  I was using *evince*, and tried *zathura* with the same result.  Fortunately *xpdf* and *cups-pdf* do work — the latter being more suitable for my use.